# Deserialize JSON object as .NET HashSet and Lists Failed

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have this kind of Json I want to save:

```
 "data": {
      "importMannerTypeList": {
        "importMannerTypeID": 5,
        "importMannerTypeDesc": "a"
      },
      "authoritySourceList": [
        {
          "authoritySourceID": 1,
          "authoritySourceDesc": "b"
        }
      ],
      "permitStatusList": {
        "permitStatusID": 4,
        "permitStatusDesc": "c"
      }}
```

All of them set as Arrays, but because `authoritySourceList` is multi select and not 1 object it look like this. here is the class that Deserialize the json, `importMannerTypeList` and `permitStatusList` failed to get the data from JSON why?

```
public class ImportPlantSettingsResponse
    {
        public ImportPlantSettingsResponse()
        {
            ImportMannerTypeList = new List<ImportMannerType>();
            AuthoritySourceList = new HashSet<AuthoritySource>();
            PermitStatusList = new List<PermitStatusResponse>();
        }

        public virtual List<ImportMannerType> ImportMannerTypeList { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AuthoritySource> AuthoritySourceList { get; set; }
        public virtual List<PermitStatusResponse> PermitStatusList { get; set; }
```

Comment: I suggest you read [Json Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) since the value of `importMannerTypeList` is not an array in Json, `permitStatusList` too.

Comment: Those are not JSON arrays, they are JSON objects.  The JSON shown in your question does not have any arrays, which are containers that begin with `[`, end with `]`, and contain comma-delimited JSON values.  See https://www.json.org/ for details.  Since Newtonsoft serializes collections such as `HashSet<T>` as a JSON array as per [the documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Lists) you will not be able to deserialize a non-array object to a hash set without a custom converter.

Answer (score 0):

As `Selim Yildiz` said,ImportMannerTypeList and PermitStatusList are not lists.Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class ImportPlantSettingsResponse
    {
        public ImportPlantSettingsResponse()
        {
            AuthoritySourceList = new HashSet<AuthoritySource>();
        }

        public virtual ImportMannerType ImportMannerTypeList { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AuthoritySource> AuthoritySourceList { get; set; }
        public virtual PermitStatusResponse PermitStatusList { get; set; }
    }
```

action:

```
public IActionResult TestImportPlantSettingsResponse([FromBody] ImportPlantSettingsResponse importPlantSettingsResponse) {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]